# Maior Dicionário da Língua Portuguesa e Acessibilidade

Tags: português-brasileiro, vocabulário, recursos-online

Recentemente busquei desenvolver um programa para resolver o conhecido jogo da forca, para o qual necessitei de um dicionário para inserir nele. A partir disso, me interessei sobre o tópico e busquei os dicionários mais completos que pude encontrar. Inicialmente, me deparei com [este site do Instituto de Matemática e Estatística da USP](https://www.ime.usp.br/%7Epf/dicios/index.html) com cerca de 245.366 termos. No entanto, aparentemente, existem outros dicionários com maior quantia de termos, desde alguns mais conhecidos como por exemplo o [VOLP](https://www.academia.org.br/nossa-lingua/busca-no-vocabulario) (382.000 entradas) e [Aulete](https://aulete.com.br/) (818.000 verbetes), até mais desconhecidos como o utilizado no [LibreOffice](https://github.com/pythonprobr/palavras) (320.000 palavras) ou mesmo [o deste site](https://github.com/AlfredoFilho/Palavras_PT-BR) de origem desconhecida com 1.228.371 palavras.

Nesse sentido, qual seria realmente a maior base de dados da língua portuguesa em termos de número de entradas, e como acessá-la? Dicionários como VOLP, Aulete, Houaiss, dentre outros, citados anteriormente, não aparentam permitir o download de seu vocabulário completo, apenas pesquisar palavras individualmente em seus mecanismos de buscas próprios, e que por vezes não se mostram tão bons.

Comment: Para seu objetivo, me parece que não precisa ser um dicionário, que uma lista de palavras basta. Alguns recursos são: https://natura.di.uminho.pt/wiki/doku.php?id=dicionarios:main ,  https://natura.di.uminho.pt/download/sources/Dictionaries/wordlists/ ,   https://www.ime.usp.br/~pf/dicios/index.html ,  https://github.com/LibreOffice/dictionaries/tree/master/pt_BR ,  mas deve haver outras, estes estão entre os primeiros hits do Google.

Comment: Agora, essa é possivelmente uma questão para o Meta. Vou esperar o retorno de outros usuários.

Comment: Você precisa é de um dicionário com API. [Aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/31885/dicion%C3%A1rio-portugu%C3%AAs-online-para-efectuar-requests) tem uma resposta e um recurso nos comentários.